# Questions about maximal submodules.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $M$ a right $A$-module, where $K$ is a field. Suppose that $M=C\oplus D$, where $C, D$ are right $A$-modules. If $C', D'$ are maximal right $A$-submodules of $C, D$ respectively, could we conclude that $C'\oplus D'$ is a maximal submodule of $M$? If $C', D'$ are the unique maximal right $A$-submodules of $C, D$ respectively, could we conclude that $C'\oplus D'$ is the unique maximal submodule of $M$? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, not at all. Take A=K, M=K^2, and C,D nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $C\bigoplus D'$ is a proper submodule properly containing $C'\bigoplus D'$.